# Why infer command is producing false positive error?

Tags: ios, logging, macros, static-analysis, cocoalumberjack

I am using CocoaLumberjack pod in my iOS project.

Defined custom macro like,

```
#define SM_DDLogDebugConst(tag, frmt)   DDLogDebug(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"[DEBUG][%@] %@", tag, frmt]), @"%@")
```

In code I used the macro like following,

```
int64_t startTime = [TimeUtils NOW]; // returns timestamp // line = 10
...
int64_t tempTime = [TimeUtils NOW];  // returns timestamp // line = 20
SM_DDLogDebug(TAG_Class, @"elapsed time: %lld", (tempTime - startTime));
...
```

The problem is when I run infer its detecting `DEAD_STORE` error in lines 10 & 20 though the variables in the lines have been used in the logging. How to resolve this issue?

**Note:** my infer command runs in two steps,

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme Main -configuration Release COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO OTHER_CFLAGS="-DNS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(A)= -D_Nullable_result=_Nullable" | tee xcodebuild.log | /usr/local/bin/xcpretty -r json-compilation-database -o compile_commands.json

/usr/local/bin/infer run --keep-going --skip-analysis-in-path Pods --compilation-database-escaped compile_commands.json
```

Comment: How exactly are you running `infer`? Most likely it is inspecting your app in release mode when your debug logs have been removed. The simplest solution would be to wrap your `startTime` and `endTime` variables into `#ifdef DEBUG` directives, or, you can hide them in macros, too, .e.g `SM_DEBUG_SAVE_START_TIME()` and `SM_DEBUG_SAVE_START_TIME()`.

Comment: @Sulthan I have added how Infer was run. Also there is no macro for skipping log in Release configuration. Is there any default setting in Lumberjack pod side you know of?

Comment: My fault. I was assuming that you are removing logs from release mode. I recommend switching Xcode to release and checking preprocessed output. That should give your more info.